# Passing an ArrayList to a TreeSet to get the sorted order of elements with removing duplicates

Tags: sorting, treeset

```java
    List<User> learnersList=null;
    List<User> instructorsList=null;
    List<User> contentCreatorsList=null;

    try {
        learnersList=getManagerFactory().getLearningMgmtManager().getAllLearners();
        SortedSet<User> userList =new TreeSet<User> (learnersList);
    } catch (ElearningException e) {
        log.error("Error in gotoinboxpage method in messagemgmt action");
    }
```

In the above code I want to sort the 'userList' in the natural ordering with unique values. I am planning to use a TreeSet. But I am not getting the list in a sorted way.  Not able to figure out whats going wrong here. The following exception is thrown instead.  Any help?

Unhandled Exception thrown: class java.lang.ClassCastException
User cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

```
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:334)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you put your object into `SortedSet`, I think you need to implement `Comparable` interface, and override `compareTo` function. Otherwise, the Collection cannot know how you want to sort object. By default, collection just sort it based on the element's natural order.